# Combinatorial property of sets

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Is the following true? For every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a finite
 subset $W$ of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$, such that
$$|p_1(W)\cap p_2(W)\cap \{p_1(x)+p_2(x):x\in W\}\cap \{p_2(x)+p_3(x):x\in W\}\cap \{p_1(x)+p_2(x)+p_3(x):x\in W\}|\geq (1-\varepsilon)|W|.$$

Here $p_i$ is the projection on the $i$-th coordinate of $W$.

Comment: Are you assuming $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$? Otherwise I'm pretty sure $W=\{0\}$ works for all $\epsilon$.

Comment: I would never assume 0 in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: FYI: $0\in\mathbb N$ in  the standard definition of $\mathbb N$ from set theory.

Comment: thanks, Tim, my remark was more a joke then something serious, mathematicians are divided on two groups: those for whom $0$ in in $\mathbb{N}$ and those for whom its not. I am from the second camp. Anything to say on the problem itself?

Comment: A construction like $W=\{(a,a,a):a \in S \}$ gives a ratio of $\dfrac{1}{6}$ with $S=\{d:d|6^n\}$ and the intersection being $T=\{6d:d|6^{n-1}\}$.